# How to print a javascript array values in a jQuery .html() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript array that contains a set of strings. I want to display them in a HTML div element by line by line using j Query or JavaScript.

My code is up to now:

```
var data = data;
for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {

  data[i] = data[i] + '<br />';

  $(target).html('<a>'+data[i]+'</a>');
}
```

My data is displayed in this moment right now.

```
Labelling MachinesLabels - Plastic, Metal, Foil etcLabels FabricLaboratories - MedicalLaboratories - TestingLaboratory Equipment & SuppliesLaboratory Equipment Services & Calibration
```

I want them displayed like this as links (inside  tags):

```
Labelling Machines
Labels - Plastic, Metal, Foil etc
Labels Fabric
Laboratories - MedicalLaboratories - Testing
Laboratory Equipment & Supplies
Laboratory Equipment Services & Calibration
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use append method check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the breaks outside of the link tags and use .html() only once, as it completely replaces the innerHTML of the given element, i.e.

```
str = "";
for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
    str += "<a>" + data[i] + "</a><br />";
}
$(target).html(str);
```

I would suggest another approach, to use innerHTML (javascript) or append (jquery) as another answer has already mentioned

```
for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
    target.innerHTML += "<a>" + data[i] + "</a><br />";
}
```

Comment: `html()` method replaces the target html every iteration of the loop

Comment: @charlietfl that's why I used append method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = data;
var str = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {

  str += `<a>${data[i]}<br /></a>`;

}
$(target).html(str);
```

Try this.

Comment: This creates only one `<a>` with a list of items in it. Doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way will be wrapped in a div. And you need to use .append() method to not override the initial data that is already added to the target.

```js
var data = ["Hello", "World", "Lorem", "Ipsum", "More length"];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $("#result").append('<div><a href="#" class="link">' + data[i] + '</a></div>');
}
```

```css
.link {
  color: #5ca5cc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Clean and more simple code along with working demo.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete here.Not sure if you have declare variable `i` anywhere in code.Also you are starting to loop from 1st index

Instead of appending to DOM on every iteration,create a string and concat the value to it. Append it on completion of the iteration.

```
var data = data,
htmlString="";
for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
htmlString+= data[i] + '<br />';
}
$(target).append(htmlString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `for/loop` you could use ES6 in one line with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
$(target).html(arr.map(el => `<a>${el}</a><br/>`));
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rs56anpd/3/)**